# Pass $(this) to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            require($(this));
        }
    });

    function require(that){
        console('Please fill in ' + $(that).data('validate-msg') + '.');
    }
```

Above code won't work, may I know how to pass `$(this)` to another function?

But without function it worked like this

```
$('input').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                console('Please fill in ' + $(this).data('validate-msg') + '.');
            }
        });
```

Comment: typo: `console()` is not a function

Comment: Can you clarify "won't work" - do you see any errors in the log etc?  Assuming `console` is your own function (and you say it works in the 2nd example), there appears to be nothing inherently wrong with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('input').each(function(){
       self = $(this)

        if(!self.val()){
            require(self);
        }
    });

    function require(that){
        console.log('Please fill in ' +that.data('validate-msg') + '.');
    }
```

Comment: With all the comments and answers and downvotes about `console.log` and you're still suggesting to try `console('...')`?!

Comment: @AlonEitan OP claims the second example works, so have to take them at their word and assume they have a function called `console`.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvoted your answer but I would at least mention something about overwriting the `console` object and why it's a bad idea in the first place (Although i'm pretty sure they meant `console.log()` in the first place anyway)

Comment: @AlonEitan  Sorry I had copied his code to make changes and forgot to add .log to to console

Comment: Ok, so i'll upvote then to cover that someone else downvote